# Illegal character in query URI Syntax

Tags: java, url

```
Illegal character in query at index 127: http://192.168.1.7:8080/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/report/genReport/generateReport?reportname=REPORT&doctype=PDF&param={"StartDate":"20140604","EndDate":"20140630","Range":"10"}
```

can any one help me to get out of this error

Comment: &param is a json object

Comment: What code give you this error?

Comment: Which is the character at index 127?

Comment: there is nothing at 127

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are trying to send a JSON object via your Get Request.

You should try [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method.

For HTTP Client & Post Method, [Check this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html)

Comment: This is not an answer, This should  be a comment.

Comment: this will not be displayed in url, i'll execute this url via httpclient.

Comment: How your answer going to solve the OP's isse?

Comment: @Shiva Check the link to see how to send POST request using HTTP Client

Comment: actually i was using httppost to execute the url,after i added namevaluepair, am getting 404,i printed httppost it printed http://192.168.1.7:8080/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/report/genReport/generateReport HTTP/1.1, where this HTTP/1.1 came, and how to know my request is going correctly to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should urlencode the JSON

```
{"StartDate":"20140604","EndDate":"20140630","Range":"10"}
```

to

```
%7B%22StartDate%22%3A%2220140604%22%2C%22EndDate%22%3A%2220140630%22%2C%22Range%22%3A%2210%22%7D
```

The URL will then be

```
http://192.168.1.7:8080/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/report/genReport/generateReport?reportname=REPORT&doctype=PDF&param=%7B%22StartDate%22%3A%2220140604%22%2C%22EndDate%22%3A%2220140630%22%2C%22Range%22%3A%2210%22%7D
```

Comment: i can't hard code the json string, it's a json string

Comment: You don't have to hard code anythin. Just have the code that generates this URL encode the JSON into a save format. That's what URL encoding ist for.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) how to do url encoding.